# Firestore doesn't read decimal point

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to sum the "quantity" values ​​of all files, but the decimal point is not read, only the integer is added, why is this?

[image]

```
 func getDatas2(){
        
        self.db.collection("Admin").document("AI智能機器人").collection("Ai日獲利").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error while getting data from server!" )
            }else{
                if snapshot?.isEmpty != true && snapshot != nil {
                    
                    for document in snapshot!.documents{
                        
                                if let quantity = document.data()["quantity"] as? Int{
                                    self.totalVotes += quantity
                                    self.new.text = "\(self.totalVotes)"
                                        
                                    
                                }
                            }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my current function that sums integers fine, values ​​with decimal points don't read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> values ​​with decimal points don't read

That is happening because you're casting a decimal number field type to an Int rather than to double:

```
if let quantity = document.data()["quantity"] as? Int
```

Int is a type of number that doesn't store decimal numbers. So to solve this you have to cast the value that you're reading from Firestore into a double like this:

```
if let quantity = document.data()["quantity"] as? Double
//
```

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem!
Can I ask again, if I put the code into the Cell, the table will be infinitely cumulative, what is the reason?

Example: only 1+1=2, but moving the table up and down will continue to 1+1+1+1=4, and then refresh will continue to add

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but if something doesn't work they you expect, then please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.